# Add System application(Through App source code/working AS project) in AOSP source code

Tags: android, operating-system, embedded, android-source

I am trying to add an application in AOSP source through app source code, not by apk . My application is simple hello world application which I have developed in Android Studio. I have wrote its `Android.mk`, placed it in `packages/app/myapplication/Android.mk`. Registered application package name in `aosp_source_code/build/target/product/handheld_system.mk`
Did I make any mistakes in `Android.mk` file? or am I missing any steps.

Here is code of my `Android.mk`

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Myapplication
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src/main/java)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/main/res
LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    android-arch-lifecycle-extensions \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-constraint-layout
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

**Errors**

```
packages/apps/Myapplication/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml:8: error: attribute defaultNavHost (aka com.myapplication:defaultNavHost) not found.
packages/apps/Myapplication/src/main/res/layout/content_main.xml:8: error: attribute navGraph (aka com.myapplication:navGraph) not found.
packages/apps/Myapplication/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml:2: error: attribute startDestination (aka com.myapplication:startDestination) not found.
packages/apps/Myapplication/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml:14: error: attribute destination (aka com.myapplication:destination) not found.
packages/apps/Myapplication/src/main/res/navigation/nav_graph.xml:24: error: attribute destination (aka com.myapplication:destination) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
11:57:34 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (4 seconds)
```

Comment: Could you show the dependencies in build.gradle of your app ?

Comment: @TuanPM, ```dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
} ```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. The build system couldn't find `app:defaultNavHost` and others in your app source code and the dependencies you've listed in `Android.mk`. It seems those attributes are defined in `androidx.navigation` library, but you've not added it in the `Android.mk` file.

Comment: @frogatto
How can i add them in AOSP ? Previously I have added some libraries to AOSP using PRODUCT_COPY_FILES. Do I need to follow similar process or something different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i saw on your build.gradle file, you probably need to link `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`, `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout`, `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui` and `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment` in your Android.mk

Example

```
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := \
    androidx.appcompat_appcompat \
    androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout \
    androidx-navigation_navigation-ui \
    androidx-navigation_navigation-fragment \
    ...
```

But `androidx-navigation_navigation-ui` and `androidx-navigation_navigation-fragment` may available or not available depend on your AOSP build system. You should check by yourself to ensure these libraries available (usually located in `prebuilts` directory). In case these libraries not available, you need to download them manually then add them to AOSP build system manually.

Comment: @semw I think you should try to add your package to PRODUCT_PACKAGES in file /<aosp-root>/build/target/product/core.mk

Comment: Thanks, It worked, If my app dependencies are not included in aosp , how can i add them manually to aosp ?